# jQuery Problem with class attribute: Why does this work in 1.2.6 and doesn't on 1.3.1?

Tags: jquery

Well... for me it's just the same thing, but I don't know why this
works in 1.2.6 and doesn't in 1.3.1:

```
if ($('.trSelected').length == 2) {
    alert("hello");
}
```

In this case, I'm selecting rows on flexigrid and used to work just
fine in 1.2.6.

To work in 1.3.1, I had to do this:

```
if ($('#flexDiv .trSelected').length == 2) {
    alert("hello");
}
```

I had to specify the table from where the trSelected are... why does
Does this happen?

I'm having too many problems with class attributes. For example: If I
have 3 input text with class "test", only the first input text is
functional... the other ones no.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

Did you debug what does the $('#flexDiv .trSelected').length return ?

Best thing for javascript debugging is Firebug.

In javascript write:

```
console.log(  $('#flexDiv .trSelected').length  );
```

And then look in your Firebug console what do you get.

Comment: You can also write `$('#flexDiv .trSelected').length` directly in the Firebug console without modifying your script. Firebug is available as a bookmarklet for non-Firefox browsers.